# Django: Limit user's session by time

Tags: django, authentication

I'm working on the app where I need to limit the ability to log in and be authenticated for a specified time of the day. Let's say from 8am to 5pm. To limit the ability to log in I created a custom auth backend where `authenticate()` method returns user object only if current time is within allowed period of time.

Now I want to terminate user's auth session after specified time.

Setting session `expiry_date` date and cookie's `Expiry` seems to be the best way to achieve this, but after reading Django docs and digging in the source code for some time I did not found a good solution to it. How do I do this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the auth backend is probably not the solution you are looking for (at least I wouldn't recommend it), since you are changing security-critical parts of your application.

I would suggest a [custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/): If registered users trying to access your site between 8am and 5pm, they'll see a warning that this site cannot be used.

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

class AccessRestrictionMiddleware:
    def process_request(self, request):
        current_hour = timezone.now().hour
        is_time_restricted = current_hour >= 8 and current_hour < 17
        if request.user.is_authenticated() and is_time_restricted:
           raise PermissionDenied
```

Comment: I'm not changing it completely, I just extend the default backend, and in the `authenticate()` method I call `super()` first and then do my job with the authenticated user (if super returns a user, means authenticated successfully). Default backend is 100% in action.

Comment: You still need to logout / show the warning if a logged in user using the website outside of the specified time. The AuthBackend however is not used if your user is requesting with a valid session, and you still need to check with a function decorator or middleware.